# The correct preposition to use with 'holiday'

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, difference, usage

This is a two-part question:

Part one: What's the difference between these two sentences below.

- Where are you going for holiday.
- Where are you going on holiday.

What exactly does 'On' and 'For' mean in the context above, and what is the difference in their implications?
In addition, if I want to use the preposition 'for' do I have to put a pronoun/article after it for the construction to be grammatically correct?
E.g. Where are you going for YOUR holiday?/ I went to Italy for A holiday.

Part two: Is the sentence 'Tell me a good place for holiday' correct? Is so, why isn't it as common as 'Tell me a good place to go on holiday'?
If it isn't correct, can I change it to 'Tell me a good place for A holiday' or 'Tell me a good place for holidaying'?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-nouns/holiday-and-holidays

Comment: I have already referred to that webpage, but it doesn't fully answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Where're you going for your holiday(s)?

Where're you going on vacation/holiday?

You normally use the preposition "on", but the use of the "for" isn't ungrammatical.

As for the sentence "Tell me a good place to go on holiday", there's nothing with it grammatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does 'ON' actually mean in 'go on holiday'. For example there are two way of interpreting ' Where to - GO ON HOLIDAY' (meaning taking a holiday) or ' Where to go -  ON HOLIDAY' (meaning at the time of holiday or when holiday comes around). Basically, where do I place the emphasis? (- indicating pause)

Answer (score 0):

"On" and "for" in this case have mostly interchangeable meaning.
Or, at least, the difference is small enough to be difficult to distinguish for a native speaker.
I believe they would be dialectical choices more than ones related to meaning.

The sentence "tell me a good place for holiday" is perfectly understandable, but might sound a bit unusual to American English speakers. American English tends to treat "holiday" as a noun whereas others seem to treat it as a verb.
"...to go on A holiday" would feel more natural to American English. "...holidayING" on "...ON holiday" I believe would be more of a UK/Australian use of the word.

Answer (score 0):

In British English, *on holiday* should be treated as an idiom: it doesn't take an article, it can't be plural, and you can't substitute a different preposition:

> Where are you going on holiday to?

> I'm on holiday next week.

Apart from that idiom, you need an article or determiner:

> When are you taking your holiday?

> After my holiday.

> I heed a holiday.

I believe that the Americans use *vacation* in the same ways, though I'm not sure.

But in BrE we sometimes use the plural, especially with a personal pronoun. I can't detect any particular different meaning in doing so:

> When I got back from my holidays ..

> He's on his holidays. (but not *He's on holidays*)

So this answers your part 2 as well: _a good place for ... holiday _ isn't the idiom, so requires an article or determiner.